# How can i add GCP > Container Registry auth key to Docker config.json?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-container-registry

How can i add Auth key from Service Account for (GCP-> Container Registry) to docker daemon.json?

Normally i write url and user:pass in base64 in docker daemon.json and docker can do pull from private registry.

How about GCP Container registry? I generated a json key and it works.

```
docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io < credentials.json
```

I can login to GCP Container Registry and pull the image from it but how can i add this Key to docker daemon.json So that the docker automatically makes a pull from private repo.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that you already choose your authentication metthod:

[Choosing an authentication method](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#methods)

- [gcloud credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#gcloud-helper)
- [Standalone docker credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#standalone-helper)
- [Access Token](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#token)
- [JSON key file](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#json-key)

Regarding JSON Key File, Use the following guidelines to limit access to your container images:

- Create dedicated service accounts that are only used to interact with Container Registry.\
- Grant the specific [role](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) for the least amount of access that the service account requires.\
- Follow [best practices for managing credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#best_practices_for_managing_credentials).

To create a new service account and a service account key for use with Container Registry repositories only:

1. Create a new service account that will interact with Container Registry.

- You can run the following commands using Cloud SDK on your local machine, or in Cloud Shell.

a. Create the service account. Replace NAME with a name for the service account.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create NAME
```

b. Grant a role to the service account. Replace PROJECT_ID with your project ID and ROLE with the appropriate Cloud Storage role for the service account.

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID --member "serviceAccount:NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/ROLE"
```

2. Obtain a key for the service account that will interact with Container Registry.

You can run the following command using Cloud SDK on your local machine, or in Cloud Shell.The instructions on this page use the file name keyfile.json for the key file.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create keyfile.json --iam-account [NAME]@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

3. Verify that [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) are correctly configured for the service account. If you are using the Compute Engine service account, you must correctly configure both permissions and access scopes.
4. Use the service account key as your password to authenticate with Docker.

Username is `_json_key` (NOT the name of your service account)
`keyfile.json` is the service account key you created

for example:

```
cat keyfile.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://HOSTNAME
```

where HOSTNAME is `gcr.io`, `us.gcr.io`, `eu.gcr.io`, or `asia.gcr.io`.

Or, for older Docker clients which don't support `--password-stdin`:

```
docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://HOSTNAME
```

where HOSTNAME is `gcr.io`, `us.gcr.io`, `eu.gcr.io`, or `asia.gcr.io`.

Comment: thanks for explanation, but your answer is not that what i asked for. Ok, I'll ask differently. How can I create a login and password for Google Cloud REGISTRY(NOT FOR ARTIFACT REGISTRY) so that they can be written to the config in this way? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configjson-properties

Comment: Thanks. And Artifact Registry and Container Registry are two different services. I'm asking about Container Registry

Comment: maybe the answer is what you will see in the second link of my answer: [gcloud credential helper](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#gcloud-helper)

```
gcloud auth login

gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT --key-file=KEY-FILE
```

Comment: I understand what you mean. But I don't want to install additional gcloud console for GCP.

Comment: i don't see anything to install in the documentation, anyway, it's a sad it didn't help you.

Comment: I should install and configure gcloud if I want to access Cloud Registry for example from my local PC.